# Can I destroy a cloned GameObject in Unity at a specific position?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im trying to make a 2d minecraft version in Unity where the terrain is generated by spawning in clones of a GameObject prefab. I wonder if there is any way I can destroy a specific GameObject on mouse click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes add a collider and this script:

```
void OnMouseDown(){
Destroy(this.gameObject);
}
```

this will destroy any object you click on that it is attached to, as long as it has a collider

Comment: In general terms, you should definitely use the "EventSystem" approach these days.  it seems more complicated at first, but it's much easier in the long run.  "OnMouseDown" etc. is basically deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a EventSystem in your 2D Project,
consider attaching this script to your prefab.

```
class Destroyable : MonoBehaviour, IPointerClickHandler {
    public void OnPointerClick(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: this is the way to go  :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use OnMouseDown. Inside it you have to use Destroy to safely delete the GameObject (free resources) and use SetActive(false) to make the object "invisible" and unusable by the player because Destroy() does not guarantee an immediate effect.

```
void OnMouseDown(){
this.gameObject.SetActive(false);
Destroy(this.gameObject);
}
```

Alternatively you can use raycast but the core code is the same. Both solutions require the object to have a collider.

[Raycast extension](https://answers.unity.com/questions/615771/how-to-check-if-click-mouse-on-object.html)

Comment: FWIW, it's actually fine to just use Destroy.  it destroys it by the *start of the next frame*.

Comment: In general terms, you should definitely use the "EventSystem" approach these days.  it seems more complicated at first, but it's much easier in the long run.  "OnMouseDown" etc. is basically deprecated.

Comment: @Fattie i got in a situation when instantiating prefabs and destroying upon touching a trigger did not work with Destroy as expected. I could access the information of a "destroyed" object in editor (although almost for like 5 seconds, but it was enough to see the object). The EventSystem approach seems cleaner tho.